# Custom Template in Azure B2C doesn't work in IE11 when JavaScript is enabled

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, internet-explorer-11, azure-ad-b2c

I have a SignIn V2 policy in Azure Active Directory B2C
[image: image 1]
I also enabled JavaScript
[image: image 2]
Because I use it to manipulate some elements in the form.

This configuration works well in Google Chrome, but whenever I try to run it in Internet Explorer 11, I get

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

In the console, and the login button doesn't respond.

[image: image 3]

This happens when JavaScript is enabled.
When I disable it, the page works in IE11 (But my manipulations don't).

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: I imagine this jquery version is not supported by ie ? could you specify the jquery version to use or is it fixed ?

Comment: I don't use jQuery directly in my template. I think that B2C injects it. The version is jquery-bundle-1.10.2.min.js (3,15655) and I have no control over it.

Comment: Currently, it appears that Azure B2C is using JQuery version 1.10, and the Azure AD B2C uses a specific version of jQuery. Don’t include another version of jQuery. Using more than one version on the same page causes issues. And, Using RequireJS isn't supported.
So, please check whether you are using another version of JQuery and requireJS. Please refer to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) and [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview) to check the detail information.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thank you, but I found what the problem was. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found out what the problem was.
I was using ES6 syntax such as

```
() => {
  ...
}
```

Once I replaced it to

```
function () {
  ...
}
```

It worked on IE11.

Thank you
@Thomas
and
@Zhi Lv - MSFT

Comment: Sofor IE 11 it does not supports lamba :-)