# Azure B2C custom login page not working in IE11

Tags: azure, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured custom login page for azure B2C it is working as expected for chrome or Mozilla but same page unable to load (empty load) on IE11.

Note : It works on microsoft edge.

Comment: Are you using es6 syntax?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732188/custom-template-in-azure-b2c-doesnt-work-in-ie11-when-javascript-is-enabled

Comment: Only description of the issue will not help to find the cause of the issue. I suggest you post a sample code of that login page. So that we can try to check and test it. You can also check the console in the IE browser to see whether it shows any error or warning message. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: this looks a browser compatibility question, not an Azure B2C